# Age from year and date column Netezza sql

Tags: sql, netezza

I have data elements like ID; start_date; Birth_year. I want to calculate Age based on the birth_year column and start_date as shown in the AGE column.

[image]

I could only think of padding the birth year with '-01-01' and then using that column to calculate Age.

Is there another efficient way to get Age from the birth year and start date in Netezza SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [extract SQL function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5FPD_1.0.0/com.ibm.ips.doc/postgresql/dbuser/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_extract_datetime.html) to get the year from start_date and do the age calcuation

E.g

```sql
select
    start_date,
    birth_year,
    -- assuming birth_year is an integer
    extract(year from start_date) - birth_year as age
from ...
```

will give

```
 START_DATE | BIRTH_YEAR | AGE
------------+------------+-----
 2000-01-15 |       1985 |  15
 2010-06-20 |       1990 |  20
 2005-12-15 |       1992 |  13
 2007-08-17 |       1998 |   9
 2020-09-15 |       1999 |  21
(5 rows)
```

---

An alternative method to get more detailed age would be to use the [Netezza 'age' SQL function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5FPD_1.0.0/com.ibm.ips.doc/postgresql/dbuser/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_date_time_funcs.html) -

```sql
select
    start_date,
    birth_year,
    age(start_date, to_date(birth_year, 'YYYY'))
from...
```

which will result in

```
 START_DATE | BIRTH_YEAR |           AGE
------------+------------+--------------------------
 2000-01-15 |       1985 | 15 years 14 days
 2010-06-20 |       1990 | 20 years 5 mons 19 days
 2005-12-15 |       1992 | 13 years 11 mons 14 days
 2007-08-17 |       1998 | 9 years 7 mons 16 days
 2020-09-15 |       1999 | 21 years 8 mons 14 days
(5 rows)
```